# Insert data from a GridView into database on a click of a Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert every row in the GridView into a table on a click of button.  My problem with the code below is that it is only inserting the first row and repeating the same record in the rest of the gridview.  For example, if i have on the first row:

```
2    ABC    ATL
```

it will repeat this for the rest of the columns.  How can i capture every row and insert it into my database?  thanks. 
Here is my code:

```
protected void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label ID = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lblID") as Label;
            Label NAME = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lblQue") as Label;
            TextBox LOC = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtPM") as TextBox;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText =
                "insert into myTable(ID, NAME, LOC ) values(@ID, @NAME,  @LOC) " +
                // "where ID=@ID;" + 
                "SELECT ID, NAME, LOC FROM MYTABLE";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NAME.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LOC.Text;

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GridView is not a right control to insert data in to database.

Comment: pls checkout my answer, all answers are looking good :)

Comment: i checked and it worked like a charm.  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView.Rows[0]` will take first row for all the rows.

Instead of that use row from your foreach declaration.

Replace

```
 Label ID = GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lblID") as Label;
```

With

```
 Label ID = row.FindControl("lblID") as Label;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :**  you have hardcoded index zero using following statement:

```
GridView1.Rows[0]
```

it will always insert first record from `GridView`

**Solution :**  increment row count for each row.

Try This:

```
 protected void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
   int index=0;
   foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {

        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

                  Label ID = GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("lblID") as Label;
                  Label NAME = GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("lblQue") as Label;
                  TextBox LOC = GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("txtPM") as TextBox;


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into myTable(ID, NAME, LOC ) values(@ID, @NAME,  @LOC) " +
                    // "where ID=@ID;" + 
                 "SELECT ID, NAME, LOC FROM MYTABLE";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NAME.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LOC.Text;

                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
                GridView1.DataBind();


        }
         index++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: nice idea for index++

Answer (score 0):

please use this code

`row.FindControl("lblID") as Label;` instead of `GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("lblID") as Label;`

and also  first execute your insert query then call your select query

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into myTable(ID, NAME, LOC ) values(@ID, @NAME,  @LOC) ";

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NAME.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LOC.Text;

cmd.ExcutrNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, NAME, LOC FROM MYTABLE";
.... //next binding  code
```